# How to take x many items to the left of a particular index from a list, including 0 many items

Tags: python

Say I have a list

```
listt = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

And I want to take 3 items to the left of index 4, I could use this

```
listt[:4][-3:]
```

And get

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

The general formula is

```
listt[:index][-places:]
```

However, this does not work if I want 0 number of items left of 4

```
listt[:4][-0:]
```

Gives

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

However, I want like to select 0 number of items, so it would  be an empty list

```
[]
```

So now I am trying to find a general formula which takes 0 number of items into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `listt[index-places:index]`.

This returns an empty list if `0 <= index < places` or `places <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
listt = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(listt[:4][4-3:])
print(listt[:4][4-0:])
```

The general formula is

```
listt[:index][index-places:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are interpreting this wrongly,
`print(listt[:4])` gives you the first 4 elements in the list

`print(listt[-3:])` gives you the last 3 elements in the list

That's why when you printed `listt[:4][-3:]`, you are actually printing the last 3 elements of `[0, 1, 2, 3]` which is `[1, 2, 3]`

Now, if you print `(listt[-0:])`, which still equals to printing `(listt[:])` & therefore gives you the whole list. Printing `listt[:4][-0:]` will be like printing the whole list of `listt[:4]` which gives you back `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Therefore, if you want to select none. It's either you select index 0 to 0 which is `print(listt[0:0])` or select up to 0 which is `print(listt[:0])`. Otherwise, you gonna get some values.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`listt[k][k-n:k]`

Negative index fails in case of zero, but this will do well. However, for n>k this won't work.